# I'm getting a package Microsoft.Build 16.3.0 is not compatible with netstandard 2.0 error

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, msbuild, .net-standard, .net-framework-version

When I first open the solution in VS2017 and trying to build a project, I get many errors and warnings in the Error list window. The project I'm trying to build is from Github (https://github.com/KirillOsenkov/SourceBrowser). Visual studio is throwing the below error. The solution has .net core 2.1 and .net framework 4.7.2. Both are already installed in my machine too.

[image]

Comment: is  netstandard2.0 installed too?

Comment: doesn't it automatically ship with the .net core package/ SDK?

Comment: the 16.3 in package name indicates VS2019, so try VS2019 Community Edition.

Comment: I'm seeing the same error if I build with VS2019.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what fixed it for me, but I installed visual studio 2015 update 3 on my machine and also updated VS2019 and VS2017 and then built the solution again. Now it builds successfully in both VS2017 and VS2019. It looks like some other package or library that supports this also installed during the update process.

Comment: You could consider marking it as [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) after the limitation of 48 hours. And to add some useful info for this issue: 1. When I first open the solution in VS2017, I get many errors and warnings in Error list window. 2. When I open the solution with VS2019 16.3.9 like the author suggests in a remote machine, no error occurs.(only several warnings) Hope it makes some help :)